# What is the best way to store and export click stream data in almost real time

Tags: database, database-design, mapreduce, large-data

Let us say I have a website which is getting lots of hits. I need to store the click data in some database so that it can be used for reporting and monitoring purposes. The click data will contain information like who is referring the users to this site, where users are coming from, what time do they come etc. 
Is there a way to store and then analyze this data in lets say 10 minute intervals so that you can get an overview of how the site is performing every 10 minutes. What type of database will be best suited for this purpose and what kind of analyzing tools can quickly generate meaningful information from this data. One option for analysis I am thinking of is using some variation of map-reduce to run the queries on this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't tried it yet [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) looks promising.

Quote:

> OpenTSDB is a distributed, scalable
>   Time Series Database (TSDB) written on
>   top of HBase. OpenTSDB was written to
>   address a common need: store, index
>   and serve metrics collected from
>   computer systems (network gear,
>   operating systems, applications) at a
>   large scale, and make this data easily
>   accessible and graphable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also came across hummingbird analytics (http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/) which is using MongoDB to store this type of data.